# XDocument reference issue c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have these 2 methods wrote in another class, but how can I reach the output off this from other classes? I wan't just the value of lsTags.

That's my code:

```
private void LoadXMLFile()
    {
        WebClient xmlClient = new WebClient();
        xmlClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(XMLFileLoaded);
        xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("codeFragments.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    private void XMLFileLoaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            string xmlData = e.Result;
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

            var tagsXml = from c in xDoc.Descendants("Tag") select c.Attribute("name");                

            foreach (string tagName in tagsXml)
            {
                Tag oTag = new Tag();
                oTag.name = tagName;
                var tags = from d in xDoc.Descendants("Tag")
                           where d.Attribute("name").Value == tagName
                           select d.Elements("oFragments");
                var tagXml = tags.ToArray()[0];

                foreach (var tag in tagXml)
                {
                    CodeFragments oFragments = new CodeFragments();
                    oFragments.tagURL = tag.Attribute("tagURL").Value;
                    //Tags.tags.Add(oFragments);
                    oTag.lsTags.Add(oFragments);
                }
                this.lsTags.Add(oTag);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add reference for System.XML in Visual studio?

Comment: please don't do that! You just deleted a question about `XmlDocument` and replaced it with one on `XDocument`! Ask a separate question! They're free!

Comment: I know that's a basic question "how to return values from a function", but the big problem is with the events i'm struggling with!

Comment: read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Learn why you did a bad thing by overwriting your question, and why you should have written a new question instead. Also, learn what downvoting means and why I downvoted your question after you completely changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not support XmlDocument. Use LINQ to XML instead.